# Slide up Bottom Sheet peek over screen top

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am wanting to implement Bottom Sheet behaviour: peek slides out over screen top at STATE_EXPANDED like at the picture. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: In other words, I need to change bottom sheet peek position at STATE_EXPANDED to above screen

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do some changes with your BottomSheet layout while listening `BottomSheetBehavior`:

```java
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mBottomSheetBehavior);  
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {  
   @Override  
   public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {  
    // Here you can implement your logic with layour change
   }  

  @Override  
  public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {  
     // Here you can implement your logic with layour change
  }  
});
```